# Databrics save pandas dataframe as CSV Azure Data Lake

Tags: python, pandas, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

I have pandas dataframe in the Azure Databricsk.
I need to save it as ONE csv file on Azure Data Lake gen2.

I've tried with :

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").csv(dstPath)
```

and

```
df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save(dstPath)
```

but now I have 10 csv files but I need one file and name it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use .coalesce(1) to pull all the data into a single partition before writing: df.coalesce(1).write... Just beware the performance can take a serious hit.

Comment: @JoelCochran it works but is it possible to name this file?  If the dstPath looks like '/mnt/path/file.csv' the folder file.csv is created instead of file.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help there. There are a lot of other threads that discuss that question. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution :

```
df.to_csv('/dbfs/mnt/....../df.csv', sep=',', header=True, index=False)
```

Comment: This works, I wonder why